# Установить QLineEdit в QLayout. Вставить шрифт в приложении отдельным файлом .ttf

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlayout, qfont, qfontdatabase

С помощью абсолютного позиционирования я расставил строчки `QLineEdit`, но когда я пытался расставить их с помощью `grid`, у меня не получалось. 
Можете помочь с этим.

Ещё вопрос, можно ли сделать **`шрифт`** в приложении отдельным файлом **.ttf**? 
У меня меняется шрифт только, если указать уже установленный.

Для примера: `QToolTip.setFont(QFont("Arial", 10))`, будет работать,

а если указать как-то так - `QToolTip.setFont(QFont("fonts/font.ttf", 10))`, то нет.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QLabel, QLineEdit, QToolTip, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout,
                             QMessageBox)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QFont, QIcon)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.window()

    def window(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Body mass index")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("img/ico.png"))

        QToolTip.setFont(QFont("Arial", 10))

        self.okBtn = QPushButton("ok")
        self.okBtn.setToolTip("calculate")

        self.exitBtn = QPushButton("exit")
        self.exitBtn.setToolTip("close the program")
        self.exitBtn.clicked.connect(QCoreApplication.instance().quit)

#       Block model for buttons
        self.Hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.Hbox.addStretch()
        self.Hbox.addWidget(self.okBtn)
        self.Hbox.addWidget(self.exitBtn)

        self.Vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.Vbox.addStretch()
        self.Vbox.addLayout(self.Hbox)

        self.setLayout(self.Vbox)

        self.m = QLineEdit(self) # mass
        self.h = QLineEdit(self) # height

        self.m.resize(190, 20)
        self.m.move(10, 20)

        self.h.resize(190, 20)
        self.h.move(10, 60)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, "Exit", "Are you sure to quit?", QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No,
                                     QMessageBox.No)

        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
             event.ignore()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = QApplication(sys.argv)

    start = App()
    start.setFixedSize(300, 150) # Window size
    start.show()

    sys.exit(root.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

я не заметил ваших попыток использовать `QGridLayout`,
но у вас есть `QVBoxLayou` и этого достаточно.

я отметил для вас как надо вставлять `шрифты`, находящиеся в файлах `.ttf`

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QLabel, 
                             QLineEdit, QToolTip, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout,
                             QMessageBox)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QFont, QIcon, QFontDatabase)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.window()

    def window(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Body mass index")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("img/ico.png"))

#        QToolTip.setFont(QFont("Arial", 10))
        QToolTip.setFont(QFont("RobotoBoldCondensedItalic", 16))          # +++

        self.okBtn = QPushButton("ok")
        self.okBtn.setToolTip("calculate")
        self.exitBtn = QPushButton("exit")
        self.exitBtn.setToolTip("close the program")
        self.exitBtn.clicked.connect(QCoreApplication.instance().quit)

        self.Hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.Hbox.addStretch()
        self.Hbox.addWidget(self.okBtn)
        self.Hbox.addWidget(self.exitBtn)

        self.m = QLineEdit(self)                                          # +++
        self.h = QLineEdit(self)                                          # +++

        self.Vbox = QVBoxLayout()

        self.Vbox.addWidget(self.m)                                       # +++
        self.Vbox.addWidget(self.h)                                       # +++
# так       
        self.Vbox.addStretch()                                            # ? попробуйте так
        self.Vbox.addLayout(self.Hbox)

# или так       self.Vbox.addStretch()                                    # ? или попробуйте так

        self.setLayout(self.Vbox)

#-        self.m = QLineEdit(self) # mass
#-        self.h = QLineEdit(self) # height
#-        self.m.resize(190, 20)
#-        self.m.move(10, 20)
#-        self.h.resize(190, 20)
#-        self.h.move(10, 60)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = QMessageBox.question(
                    self, 
                    "Exit", 
                    "Are you sure to quit?", 
                    QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No,
                    QMessageBox.No
        )

        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
             event.ignore()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = QApplication(sys.argv)

# ++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont(                                                        # +++
        "D:\_Qt\Python-Examples\_PyQt5\Font\Fonts\Roboto\Roboto-BoldCondensedItalic.ttf")
# ++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                        

    start = App()
#    start.setFixedSize(300, 150)                                   # установие если вам надо
    start.show()

    sys.exit(root.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Шрифт можно загрузить вот так:

```
id = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(const QString &fileName)
if id != -1: 
    font_families = QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(id);
    print( font_families );
```

Насчет грида (если имеется в виду QGridLayout), то вот так:

```
layout = QGridLayout()
# Первая строка
layout.addWidget(widget1, 0, 0) # первая колонка
layout.addWidget(widget2, 0, 1) # вторая колонка

#Вторая строка
layout.addWidget(widget3, 1, 0)
layout.addWidget(widget4, 1, 1) 

# Устанавливаем лейаут в родительский виджет
parentWidget.setLayout(layout)
```